# Why do the Android docs say intent extras need package prefix

Tags: android, android-intent

According to the Android docs Intent extra name must have a package prefix. I've been using Intent extra names without prefixes for a long time and it seems like there is no chance of collision since what really matters is the Intent action being unique. So are the docs just wrong or am I missing something?

The docs for [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) say:

Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe the Android docs recommend using fully-qualified extras is to handle an uncommon edge case. The edge case is when you are:

- Writing an Activity that can be started using a public Intent action such as Intent.ACTION_VIEW

AND

- For your own usage you want to be able to pass custom extras to the Activity described above without interfering with another Activity that is doing the exact same thing and might have extras with the same name but different meanings or format

Phew, it all sounds very unlikely. If you aren't handling public Intent actions then it still seems as though there is no need to fully-qualify your extras, but I guess it doesn't hurt to do it all the time if you are the paranoid type.

Comment: Could you not just supply the package as an extra as well? In cases like those it seems you'd be better off checking its originating package first and then handling the Extras based on that, unless some of your sending Activities can add extras with the meanings of other sending Activities (which could end up very confusing, but might have use if you're setting up some sort of proxy Activity or Service that manipulates the extras of the Intents it passes along).

Comment: I agree with @JAB. Wouldn't the default be that you're not handling the "extra" intent data any differently based on the requester, but if you were to do that, you'd require that a package name be provided as an additional "extra" intent data so you could easily distinguish **and** validate?

Comment: You could supply and require the your package name as yet another extra and that would keep your app safe, but other apps won't check for that non-standard extra. So if you you use a public intent action and don't fully qualify all your non-standard extra names you could break other apps.

Answer (score 3):

Intents can be passed on to other apps and the system it self, so courtesy is to use a package namespace.

Comment: I don't see why it would courteous. Why would the system or other apps be looking at my extras, shouldn't they just blindly pass it along? Secondly the action has the package name in it, why would every single extra need it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [official tutorials](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity):

> It's a good practice to define keys for intent extras with your app's
>   package name as a prefix. This ensures that the keys are unique, in
>   case your app interacts with other apps.

Unless your app interacts with other apps, or you foresee that it might need to do so in the future, you can safely omit package prefixes in your extras.